# Upgrading to iOS 9.1 simulator makes Calabash not recognize the device target

Tags: ruby, cucumber, xcode7, calabash, calabash-ios

xcode installation location: `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`

xcode version: `Xcode 7.2` Build version `7C68`

calabash version: `0.16.4`

```
calabash.framework version: `0.16.4`
profiling: /Users/moody/git/calabash/calabash-ios-server/build/framework/version-tool/Build/Intermediates/calabash.build/Debug/version.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.gcda: cannot open: No such file or directory
profiling: /Users/moody/git/calabash/calabash-ios-server/build/framework/version-tool/Build/Intermediates/calabash.build/Debug/version.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.gcda: cannot open: No such file or directory
profiling: /Users/moody/git/calabash/calabash-ios-server/build/framework/version-tool/Build/Intermediates/calabash.build/Debug/version.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.gcda: cannot open: No such file or directory
profiling: /Users/moody/git/calabash/calabash-ios-server/build/framework/version-tool/Build/Intermediates/calabash.build/Debug/version.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.gcda: cannot open: No such file or directory
```

(I'm getting the top text after I upgraded from `0.14.3` to `0.16.4`, before that it would only tell me `0.14.3` without the extra stuff)

Here's the problem:
When I updated the Simulator version in Xcode and in our `01_launch.rb` from `8.4` to `9.1`, my calabash features will not run. Here is the error I'm getting:

```
No device_target was specified and did not detect a connected device. Set a device_target option in the relaunch method. (RuntimeError)
  /Users/myname/.calabash/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.14.3/lib/calabash-cucumber/launcher.rb:684:in `default_uia_strategy'
  /Users/myname/.calabash/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.14.3/lib/calabash-cucumber/launcher.rb:627:in `relaunch'
  /Users/myname/Development/sprayerMobile/SprayMobile/features/support/01_launch.rb:35:in `Before'
Retrying.. Errno::ECONNREFUSED: (Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 37265 (http://localhost:37265))
Retrying.. Errno::ECONNREFUSED: (Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 37265 (http://localhost:37265))
Failing... Errno::ECONNREFUSED
  Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 37265 (http://localhost:37265) (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
  /Users/myname/.calabash/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:799:in `initialize'
  /Users/myname/.calabash/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:799:in `new'
  /Users/myname/.calabash/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:799:in `create_socket'
  /Users/myname/.calabash/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:747:in `block in connect'
  /Users/myname/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:88:in `block in timeout'
  /Users/myname/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:98:in `call'
  /Users/myname/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:98:in `timeout'
  /Users/myname/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:124:in `timeout'
  /Users/myname/.calabash/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:746:in `connect'
  /Users/myname/.calabash/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:612:in `query'
  /Users/myname/.calabash/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:164:in `query'
  /Users/myname/.calabash/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient.rb:1191:in `do_get_block'
  /Users/myname/.calabash/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient.rb:974:in `block in do_request'
  /Users/myname/.calabash/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient.rb:1082:in `protect_keep_alive_disconnected'
  /Users/myname/.calabash/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient.rb:969:in `do_request'
  /Users/myname/.calabash/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient.rb:822:in `request'
  /Users/myname/.calabash/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient.rb:725:in `post'
  /Users/myname/.calabash/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.14.3/lib/calabash-cucumber/http_helpers.rb:57:in `block in make_http_request'
  /Users/myname/.calabash/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.14.3/lib/calabash-cucumber/http_helpers.rb:50:in `times'
  /Users/myname/.calabash/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.14.3/lib/calabash-cucumber/http_helpers.rb:50:in `make_http_request'
  /Users/myname/.calabash/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.14.3/lib/calabash-cucumber/http_helpers.rb:29:in `http'
  /Users/myname/.calabash/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.14.3/lib/calabash-cucumber/connection_helpers.rb:11:in `http'
  /Users/myname/.calabash/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.14.3/lib/calabash-cucumber/map.rb:71:in `raw_map'
  /Users/myname/.calabash/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.14.3/lib/calabash-cucumber/map.rb:23:in `map'
  /Users/myname/.calabash/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.14.3/lib/calabash-cucumber/core.rb:112:in `query'
  /Users/myname/.calabash/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.14.3/lib/calabash-cucumber/tests_helpers.rb:23:in `element_does_not_exist'
  /Users/myname/.calabash/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.14.3/lib/calabash-cucumber/tests_helpers.rb:30:in `element_exists'
  /Users/myname/Development/company/Company/features/support/01_launch.rb:43:in `Before'
```

This error goes away when I switch back to `8.4` Has anyone experienced this, or maybe knows of a way to fix this issue? To me it seems like a simulator issue, since when I switch back b/w the simulators, in `9.1` I get those errors, where with `8.4` my features run fine.. but my coworker put in some Xcode 7 updates that I pulled into my code, so it's possible that it has to do with his updates too...

As an aside, why is it refering to `0.14.3` gems if I upgraded to `0.16.4`?

*Update

When I add `DEBUG=1` before running features, I get these warnings:

```
WARN: deprecated '1.5.0' - Replaced with RunLoop::Xcode
/Users/myname/.calabash/gems/run_loop-1.5.6/lib/run_loop/xctools.rb:183:in `xcode_version_gte_51?'
/Users/myname/.calabash/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.14.3/lib/calabash-cucumber/launcher.rb:490:in `default_launch_method'
/Users/myname/.calabash/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.14.3/lib/calabash-cucumber/launcher.rb:420:in `default_launch_args'
/Users/myname/.calabash/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.14.3/lib/calabash-cucumber/launcher.rb:534:in `relaunch'
/Users/myname/Development/sprayerMobile/SprayMobile/features/support/01_launch.rb:36:in `block in <top (required)>'
WARN: deprecated '1.5.0' - Replaced by RunLoop::Xcode
/Users/myname/.calabash/gems/run_loop-1.5.6/lib/run_loop/sim_control.rb:21:in `xctools'
/Users/myname/.calabash/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.14.3/lib/calabash-cucumber/launcher.rb:666:in `default_uia_strategy'
/Users/myname/.calabash/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.14.3/lib/calabash-cucumber/launcher.rb:627:in `relaunch'
/Users/myname/Development/sprayerMobile/SprayMobile/features/support/01_launch.rb:36:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/myname/.calabash/gems/cucumber-1.3.20/lib/cucumber/core_ext/instance_exec.rb:48:in `instance_exec'
WARN: deprecated '1.5.0' - Replaced with RunLoop::Instruments
/Users/myname/.calabash/gems/run_loop-1.5.6/lib/run_loop/xctools.rb:265:in `instruments'
/Users/myname/.calabash/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.14.3/lib/calabash-cucumber/launcher.rb:666:in `default_uia_strategy'
/Users/myname/.calabash/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.14.3/lib/calabash-cucumber/launcher.rb:627:in `relaunch'
/Users/myname/Development/sprayerMobile/SprayMobile/features/support/01_launch.rb:36:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/myname/.calabash/gems/cucumber-1.3.20/lib/cucumber/core_ext/instance_exec.rb:48:in `instance_exec'
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you by any chance name your xcode differently than the default name? For example xCode 7.1 or xCode 7.2 etc? Calabash might be looking in de xCode 7.1 directory to find the 9.1 simulator, while it is in the xCode 7.2 directory. Also, what does your terminal say when you type 'xcode-select -p'?

Comment: As far as I can tell, Xcode is named Xcode everywhere.. I don't think that would be it, because my 8.4 simulator recognized it.. it's only when I switch to 9.1 simulator that I get those errors...

when I type 'xcode-select -p' in the terminal, I get "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer"

Comment: Please use code formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After installing a new Xcode or moving/renaming an Xcode installation, you need to restart your machine.

You have a mismatch between the gem version (0.14.3) and the server version in your app (0.16.4).  Please see the [Updating your Calabash iOS version](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki/Updating-your-Calabash-iOS-version).

I believe that your run-loop version is not compatible with Xcode 7.2.

If you are not using a Gemfile, we recommend that you start.

Comment: yesssss, a combination of this worked. what i did was i updated the run-loop and calabash-ios version in gemfile.lock file.. when i updated the calabash framework yesterday, there was still a mismatch with what was in the gemfile.lock file, and it looked like the run-loop version i had was maybe incompatible with xcode 7.2, so i updated to the latest run-loop version (2.0.3). i also updated the calabash-ios version to 0.16.4 to match what i had in the terminal. after i did a bundle install and rebuilt the app, it ran in the simulator! thanks, Joshua!

Comment: Joshua, a followup question.. noticed that on some of my tests that I send to background and bring up again, that those tests are failing now.. get this message: 

uia action failed because: Input: var x = target.deactivateAppForDuration(2.0); var MAX_RETRY=5, retry_count = 0; while (!x && retry_count < MAX_RETRY) { x = target.deactivateAppForDuration(2.0); retry_count += 1}; x

I noticed at this link https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/blob/develop/changelog/0.16.3.md that "Sending apps to the background is broken on Xcode 7 simulators and iOS 9 devices."  is this still broken in 0.16.4?

Comment: The current latest is 0.17.0 (soon to be 0.17.1). We always recommend using the latest version.

Comment: Hey Christopher, I would go to 0.17.0 for calabash, except I get the error that's here: https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/issues/959 .. basically it tells me "Unable to auto detect APP_BUNDLE_PATH. Have you built your app for simulator?" And when I try to put in the bundle path manually, it can't find it either.. when that issue will be fixed, I'll definitely switch to the latest version. Thanks for responding!

Comment: irradio Please don't let the auto-detection keep you from 0.17.1.  If you need help finding your .app, please ask for help with that in another question.  Apple broke dactivateAppForDuration. 0.17.0 has the fix.

Comment: Okay, went to 0.17.1 .. seems to work. Only thing is that I can't start the test server from the terminal, but that's no big deal b/c I can just run the simulator from Xcode. And it still doesn't detect the APP_BUNDLE_PATH automatically so I had to do that thing in the ci folder where I exported the APP_BUNDLE_PATH and it worked. So things are good for the most part now, thanks!!